# Deleting variables from a local script and loading existing database data

Tags: c#, mongodb, methods

Say we have a class PersonInfo

```
PersonInfo{
public int age = 10;
public int weight = 150;
}
```

and I uploaded this data to my Mongo DB.

Now, say I dont need wieght anymore, so my PersonInfo class looks like this:

```
PersonInfo{
public int age = 10;
}
```

But now, when I load from the Mongo DB it says,
"FormatException: Element 'weight' does not match any field or property of class PersonInfo."

How can I remove class variables without getting this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this problem depending on what you're doing with your data.

By default as you've seen the driver will throw an exception if it can't deserializer all the bson document properties, this is so that we don't end up with some data loss.

The simplest approach is to add a `ExtraElements` property to your model that you're deserializing in to, this can be of either a `BsonDocument` or an `IDictionary<string, object>`.

```cs
public class PersonInfo
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public BsonDocument ExtraElements { get; set; }
}
```

Alternately we can just ignore any extra elements that are in the document in a couple of ways.

The first one is adding a `BsonIgnoreExtraElements` attribute to our class

```cs
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class PersonInfo
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, we can create a class map for our `PersonInfo` in code by executing the following before running our query (this only needs to be executed once, ideally on application startup).

```cs
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<PersonInfo>(map =>
{
    map.AutoMap();
    map.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
});
```

The next approach is if you want to apply to ignore extra elements across all or a range of types matching a predicate.

Here we're using a convention that we'll set up on application startup.

```cs
ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreExtraElements", new ConventionPack
{
    new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true)
}, t => true);
```

The `t => true` predicate will apply the convention to all types.

Comment: Awesome explanation! Thank you Kevin :)